# Flutter form builder package image picker firestore flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, imagepicker

i am using  `FormBuilderImagePicker` from package Flutter form builder

I want to use the img path but i am not able to do so

```
sending() async {
var storageimage =
    FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('/google/google');
var task = storageimage.putFile();
imgurl = await (await task.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
// await Firestore.instance.collection('twst').add(
//   {
//     'img': imgurl.toString(),
//   },
// );
```

}

i want to use that function with the imagepicker
but the problem is i am not able to find path to use putfile

Answer (score 0):

To get the path of the **FormBuilderImagePicker**, the [**toString()**](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_form_builder/latest/flutter_form_builder/FormBuilderImagePicker-class.html) method of the class prints the path.

Here is an [example](https://github.com/syntacops/flutter_formbuilder_example/blob/master/lib/main.dart#L347) of how you can print in a **container the Text field including  FormBuilderImagePicker** which have the path.

Then you will need to pass the image or file to the **putFile** method.

You can also use the **ImagePicker [pickImage](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker)** class method to get the file.

```
sending() async {
   
    File image;
    try {
      //Get the file from the image picker and store it
      image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    // Throws error when you don't select any image or when you don't have permissions 
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      return;
    }

    //Create a reference to the location you want to upload to in firebase
    StorageReference reference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("/google/google");

    //Upload the file to Firebase
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = reference.putFile(image);

    StorageTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;

    // Waits till the file is uploaded then stores the download URL
    String url = await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();

}
```